# Is learning Java enough to make good Android Apps?

Tags: java, android

So I have been learning Some JAVA And I'm wondering, Is it enough to make Apps for Android ? and what about iOS ? 
And Is java good enough to make graphical interface programs for Operzting systems ?

Comment: No, it’s not. Just because you know how to paint doesn’t mean you can make great paintings.

Comment: learning some java isn't even enough necessarily, to make a good java program( as daniel B kind of points out).  But that aside.. There's something else some kind of android framework.. To even generate a small android app that does nothing, you have to use like ant or gradle which is a "builder" of some kind. There's a bat file, android.bat which can generate a small android app.. Not even a good one

Comment: Well, there is a cheat way, where one shouldn't know about any language to be able to write his own app on Android in a few hours (or a few days if it's a big project), If you won't to feed yourself and family by earning on Apps, but just need some simple program, try it out first, before mess up with Java: http://appinventor.mit.edu/ When you would be able to call native Android API  from that tool, then start moving to learn it deeply with Java, but if you see programing for Android as for profit then start with those advised online courses.

Answer (score 1):

No, obviously - NO.
There a bunch of concepts(Activity, fragments, manifests...) that you need to know before you start programming.

Take a free online courses from Stanford University http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/lectures.shtml

It would be a fastest and most productive way to learn it.

Comment: and he should learn java first prior to android. I've seen a similar course that listed java as a pre-requisite.  Funny thing about apps, many people think oh it's just an app and they have no idea absolutely no idea what they are getting themselves into.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in developing software for the Android platform, [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org), a [massive open online course (MOOC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) provider, offers Android development courses from professors at major universities. You can take the courses for free; if you want a verified certificate you can show an employer or someone else, you can pay a nominal fee or the course. You can find such courses by [a search using "android"](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=android). There is one that just started on July 22 that lasts until August 28 titled "[Programming Mobile Applications for Android Handheld Systems: Part 1](https://www.coursera.org/course/androidpart1)" taught by [Dr. Adam Porter](https://www.coursera.org/instructor/android) at the University of Maryland, College Park. If you don't need a verified certificate, you don't even have to take tests or submit assignments; the videos and course materials are available to anyone who registers for the courser. You will also find a variety of other programming courses available through Coursera as well as courses in many other subject areas, e.g. chemistry, economics, history, philosophy, etc.

Another MOOC provider, [edX](https://www.edx.org/) also [offers android courses](https://www.edx.org/course?search_query=android) as well as may courses in other areas. As with Coursera, you can take courses for free, if you don't need a verified certificate showing successful completion of a course. The [Introduction to Mobile Application Development Using Android](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-mobile-application-hkustx-comp107x) course there starts on July 28. It is offered through the Hong Kong University of Science and Technology. It will be taught by [Joseph K Muppala](https://www.edx.org/bio/jogesh-k-muppala), an Associate Professor of Computer Science and Engineering at the School of Engineering, The Hong Kong University of Science and Technology. He received his Ph.D. in Electrical Engineering from Duke University in 1991.

Another source for Android development courses is [Udemy](http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=kd/Y23PG*g0&offerid=323085.261&type=3&subid=0), which is running a sale on its courses for $10 until midnight U.S. Pacific Standard Time (PST) on July 29 (the promo code is KEEPCOOL1110). One of the courses offered there is "Android 5.0 Lollipop: App Development for Beginners". Another is "The Complete Android & Java Developer: Build 21 Android Apps". You can also find iOS courses there; I'm not aware of any iOS courses offered by Coursera or edX, but I've been more interested in Android courses, so haven't checked their sites regularly for such courses.

The MOOC courses often have tens of thousands of students taking a course from throughout the world and the forums for their courses also give you an opportunity to learn from your fellow students. The courses usually attract a wide range of people; some will be just staring to learn programming while others will be experienced programmers, perhaps familiar with other programming languages or just seeking to enhance their skills in a language.

Comment: another is udacity